# RabbitMQ Delay message plugin not working

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I running RabbitMQ server (v3.6.2). Installed

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange
```

Created this exchange:
[image]

And inserting a message to `delay` exchange in that way:

```
public void Send(string data)
{
    var properties = Channel.CreateBasicProperties();
    properties.Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    properties.Headers.Add("x-delay", 7000);
    Channel.BasicPublish("delay", "", properties, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
}
```

It's seems like the message is leaving the exchange (`delay`), but never arrive to my queue (`IDG`).

Why?

Comment: Where is a binding between exchange and queue?

Comment: I was working according to this https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/ article. I didn't find any material about it there. Anyway, when I add the exchange binding to my queue (`IDG`), the message immediately leave the exchange and enter the queue - without waiting the `x-delay` time as expected.

Comment: Re-run your test using the latest version of RabbitMQ. 3.6.2 is very out-of-date and not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a bad type of exchange. Exchange must be of type *"x-delayed-message"* and set the exahnge type in the parameter via the property *"x-delayed-type"* to *"header"*.

See [Cannot declare a delayed message exchange with 3.8.1](https://github.com/rabbitmq/discussions/issues/20)

I use this type of exhange in C#:

```
 var exchangeArgumets = new Dictionary<string, object>
 {
       { "x-delayed-type", "header" }
 };
 channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "MyExchangeName", type: "x-delayed-message", durable: true, arguments: exchangeArgumets);
```

Comment: Not working with rabbitmq 3.10 image. looks like they have disable/removed delay message plyugin

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @luke Bakken, reinstalling rabbitmq-server with the latest version (3.7.16) solved the problem and now it's working!